# How to change background color of hovered/highlighted item of <p:selectOneMenu>?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I change the background color of hovered/highlighted item of `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

I tried the following CSS selectors, but they did not have any effect.

```css
.ui-selectonemenu-items :hover{
    background-color: #a9c6c9;
}
.ui-selectonemenu-label:hover {
    background-color: #a9c6c9;
}
```

Here is the JSF code:

```html
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="by id" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="by owner" itemValue="2" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

HTML output:

```
<ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset" style="">
     <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">Select Net</li>
     <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight">TEST</li>
     <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">TEST1</li>
     <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all">TEST2</li>
```

Comment: Anus could you please update your post with html code?

Comment: Poor Angus doesnt deserve to be an Anus.... either way, please can you post your HTML. Thanks.

Comment: Angus, they were more asking for the JSF-generated HTML output (exactly as you see when doing rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser), simply because CSS works directly with the HTML DOM tree and not with the JSF component tree (and therefore your JSF code snippet is ununderstandable to the average CSS expert). In future JSF+CSS problems/questions, you should look at/provide the JSF-generated HTML output, not the raw JSF source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-item.ui-selectonemenu-list-item.ui-state-highlight {
    background: #a9c6c9;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Chrome dev tools (press F12), it's the `.ui-state-highlight` class which is responsible for the background appearance on `.ui-selectonemenu-item` element.

[image]

So, you need to override that class instead.

```css
.ui-selectonemenu-item.ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: #a9c6c9;
}
```

Firefox (Firebug) and IE9 have by the way the same tooling. Rightclick the element in the HTML representation and choose *Inspect Element*, or just press F12 to see it.

Comment: if i will add color to .ui-selectonemenu-item.ui-state-highlight then the text color will be change but not the background

Comment: That's fully as expected. The `color` property only changes the foreground (text) color. To change the background color, you need the `background-color` property, exactly as demonstrated in your own question and my answer.

Comment: don't know what i am doing wrong but it's not working for me. thanks for the help